# OAuth Token Middleware Slim version 3 halt or exit

Tags: php, oauth, access-token, middleware, slim-3

I am trying to develop a simple authentication method. If the user has the right access token then the app will continue running, otherwise it would exit with a 401 (Unauthorized) status code.

I've got something like this:

**api.php**

```
...
$headers = getallheaders();
$auth = new OAuth2Auth($headers, $authconfig);
$app->add($auth, $dbconfig);

$app->post('/user', function($req, $res, $args) {
   //MY CODE ONLY FOR LOGGED IN USERS
});
```

**OAuth2Auth.php**

```
public function __construct($headers, $dbconfig) {
    $this->whiteList = array('\/auth');
    $this->config = $dbconfig;
    $this->headers = $headers;
}

public function __invoke($req, $res, $next) {
   $authHeader = $this->headers['Authorization']; //grabbing the token
   $auth = new AuthService($this->dbconfig); 
   $validated = $auth->verifyOAuth($authHeader); //Verifying Token against DB
   if ($validated){
       $response = $next($request, $response);
   }else{
       //EXIT, STOP or HALT
   }
   return $response;
}
```

I have tried multiples solution to avoid the Middleware to continue its execution but nothing works. the app always runs what it's inside $app->post('/user'...). I have found multiples solutions for Slim v2 but nothing so far for Slim v3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Slim v3 handles a bit different Middleware compared with v2. The answer was to create my own $response like this:

```
public function __invoke($req, $res, $next) {
   $authHeader = $this->headers['Authorization']; //grabbing the token
   $auth = new AuthService($this->dbconfig); 
   $validated = $auth->verifyOAuth($authHeader); //Verifying Token against DB
   if ($validated){
       return $response = $next($request, $response)
                        ->withStatus(200);//OK
   }else{
       return $response->withStatus(403);//Forbidden
   }

}
```

This helped me 
[How to use Middleware to control auth flow](http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/how-to-use-middleware-to-control-auth-flow/1197/2)